# How to copy row wise from one excel file to another using python

Tags: python, excel

I'm reading an excel file in the following way:

```
import xlrd
import openpyxl
book = xlrd.open_workbook("file.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)


for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows): # skip heading row
    timestamp, text, header, transporter, device_type = sheet.row_values(row_index, end_colx=5)
    #print "Row %d: Timestamp=%r Text=%r Header=%r Transporter=%r Device_Type=%r" %(row_index + 1, timestamp, text, header, transporter, device_type)
    print (text)
```

After this I'm performing some NLP on the cells in the Text column. After the NLP, the data from the "Text" column is in the following form:

```
result = [('good', 'rain a lot maybe damage.'), ('gibber', 'x screen'),....]
```

Now, I want to write this in a new excel file such that if from the above list, an element has "good" (in the first element of the tuple), then copy the whole row from the old excel file (the one which I was reading earlier), and if the element (in the above list) has "gibber" (in the first element of the tuple),then don't copy that row (from the old excel file) into the new excel file.

I'm thinking it in these lines: Create a new list using the above list such that whenever we get "good", we append the element location to the new list, otherwise we append "0" (or don't append), so the new list will be of the form:
`[1,0,...]` And then copy data only these row numbers from the new list into the new excel file.

```
temp_list=[]
for i in range(len(result)):
    if result[i][0] == 'good':
        temp_list.append(i+2)
    else:
        continue
print(temp_list)
```

After this temp_list is : `[2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,...]` i.e., rows numbers corresponding exactly with the rows I need to copy from the old excel sheet. Don't know how to proceed after that. Please help!

Comment: Why do you have `import xlrd` and `import openpyxl`?

Comment: he was probably trying to read it using `openpyxl` as well?